# Why does PowerShell script indicates failure locally even when it executes correctly on remote?

Tags: powershell

When I tested this on the remote machine directly, it works perfectly.

```
Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\MySite' -Name physicalPath
```

However, when I try using the Invoke-Command syntax from my machine, it fails with

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMMachine -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\CIDashboard' -Name physicalPath
}
```

and if I make a script file with that command, that fails with the same error

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RMMachine -FilePath 'C:\PowerShell\GetSetIISPath.ps1'
```

As a long-shot, I tried `Import-WebAdministration` locally but no luck. Note that `Copy-Item` to that machine from mine works great ruling out any connection issues.

I am running PowerShell in Admin mode on both local and remote machines.

**Further observation** - I tried to execute the same command after doing a `Enter-PSSession RMMACHINE` and I am getting the same error! This means that the `Get-ItemProperty` works only if physically typed at the terminal on that machine. So, what authentication config am I missing? Note that I am logged in as the same AD user on both machines.

Comment: Have the remote code check to verify that the module is loaded in the remote session.

Comment: @EBGreen - It is loaded. I loaded it to get the command to run on the remote machine in the first place.

Comment: That would have been a different session.

Comment: Did you run `Import-Module WebAdministration` *inside* the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock?

Comment: Just because you import a module on your LOCAL COMPUTER doesn't mean that module becomes available in a REMOTE SESSION. Import the module in the REMOTE SESSION.

Comment: @EBGreen - Worked ! Thanks. I made the (wrong) assumption that once I imported the module on both machines, that would be sufficient. Ansgar -  Thanks for your comment, I had imported on both machines but not before invoking the failed command every time. Still feeling my way around Powershell ....